# cloudbuild.yaml build pipeline for python flask app on gcloud compute engine

Tags: python, flask, google-compute-engine, apt-get, google-cloud-build

I have a Python Flask app which needs a library which is not preinstalled on Gcloud compute instances `libsndfile1` — also why I can't run this through app engine. I have set up a cloud build pipeline so my `cloudbuild.yaml` triggers every time I push to master on my repository.

Here are my 2 questions:

1. Where does the cloudbuild.yaml execute it's instructions?
2. How do I make the cloudbuild.yaml execute `apt-get install libsndfile1 python3 python3-pip` and then also execute `pip3 install requirements.txt` where `requirements.txt` is a file in the repository that triggers the cloud build?

Disclaimer: I am an ultra-beginner with docker but if you think that docker is the only way to do it then please explain how something like this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in App Engine, my recommendation would be to migrate your application to the Google App Engine Flexible environment, where you could choose a [Custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build) for your Flask application. Simply include a step on your Dockerfile to install the required library. It should look similar to this:

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y libsndfile1
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["gunicorn", "main:app", "-b", ":8080", "--timeout", "300"]
```

And within this context you could use Cloud Build to automate your deployments in a fairly easy manner by following the relevant section of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-appengine).

Now regarding your questions.

***(1) Where does the cloudbuild.yaml execute it's instructions?***

Here you can find all the relevant information of how Cloud Build works [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/overview) and to answer your first question Cloud Build is a separate service and runs each step of the build in a Docker container within Google's Infrastructure.

***(2) How do I make the cloudbuild.yaml execute `apt-get install libsndfile1 python3 python3-pip` and then also execute `pip3 install requirements.txt` where requirements.txt is a file in the repo that triggers the cloud build.***

Please notice that Cloud Build is more oriented to be used with other products like Cloud Run, GKE, Cloud Functions, etc. And the only fairly straightforward that I've seen Cloud Build being used in the context of Compute Engine would be to [build VM images using Packer](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/building/build-vm-images-with-packer). In which case you'll need to [create a custom image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images) with all the dependencies already installed along within your application.

The specifics of the solution will vary depending on the OS of your Compute Engine instance. But you'll basically need to do the following:

1. Upload a startup script that installs `libsndfile1` as well as all the dependencies specified on the `requirements.txt` file to a bucket in Cloud Storage.
2. Take advantage that you can use gcloud to [apply a startup script to running instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#startupscriptrunninginstances) in a similar fashion to.

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata example-instance \
    --metadata startup-script-url=gs://bucket/file
```

and there is [cloud builder for gcloud](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gcloud)
3. Build a cloudbuild.yaml file that uses 2. and restart the instance (not recommended if your app is in production since it will cause downtime) in a similar fashion to:

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ['compute', 'instances', 'add-metadata', 'example-instance','--metadata startup-script-url=gs://bucket/file']
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ['compute', 'instances', 'reset', 'example-instance']
```

4. Give the cloud build service account enough permissions to execute that task ([Compute Admin](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.admin) and [Storage Admin](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles)).
5. Run the build.

I shared the previous steps in aims of answering your concrete question but I would insist that my recommendation would be to migrate the app to App Engine Flexible environment with custom runtime as explained before.

Comment: Hey @NikitaJerschow, how is your work coming along? Did you find any issues? Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Hey Daniel, I went with the flex/custom direction. Way easier than I initially thought. I've never worked with docker before and still don't know how to test it locally but for the time being its working well.

Comment: I'm glad Daniel's answer was helpful. Comprehensive documentation on Dockerfile can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/). The docs will help you understand the creation and usage of Dockerfile. Moreover, I think this [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/about-custom-runtimes) has the relevant information about App Engine Flex environment custom runtimes.